# Lejos on OSX 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I have Lion OSX installed on my Mac and I want to use my mac to develop on Lejos.

I searched a lot for a decent install guide but I couldn't find one. So, I tried other tutorials online but it won't work. I first installed everything from the CD; I also installed the fantom driver.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.sjefdesign.nl/?p=651), but when I did `nxjbrowse -u`, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lejos/pc/tools/NXJBrowser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lejos.pc.tools.NXJBrowser
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Which is basically the same error I get when the device is not connected. (Although it really *is*.)

I also installed the plugin in Eclipse (32-bit) and then tried to flash the firmware and I got this error:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
flashing the firmware failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: magic string not found
See Eclipse error log for detailed stack trace.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather simple , use lejos 0.9 and not 0.85.